# Use the properties of logarithms to write the expression as a single term

Tags: calculus, logarithms

I am asked to use the properties of logarithms to write the following expression as a single term:

$(1/2)\ln(4t^4) - \ln b $

I have the solution here but I get stumped halfway through:

$(1/2)\ln(4t^4) - \ln b $

$= \ln (4t^4)^{(1/2)} - \ln b $

$ \mathbf{4t^4 = (2t^2)^2 => }$

$ \mathbf{ =
\ln ((2t^2)^2)^{(1/2)} - \ln b }$

I don't quite understand how that transformation (the lines I bolded) takes place? I get that the first $4$ can turn into $2^2$, but what happened to the exponent of $4$? Why did that get turned into a $2$?

$ = \ln (2t^2) - \ln b $

$ = \ln \frac{2t^2}{b} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $4t^4=4(t^4),$ not $(4t)^4$.  Now, using the properties of exponents
$$(2t^2)^2=2^2(t^2)^2=4t^4$$

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{array}\\
\frac12\ln(4t^4) - \ln b
&=\ln((4t^4)^{1/2}) - \ln b
\qquad u\ln(v) = \ln(v^u)\\
&=\ln(2t^2) - \ln b\\
&=\ln\left(\dfrac{2t^2}{b}\right)
\qquad \ln(u)-\ln(v) = \ln(\frac{u}{v})\\
\end{array}
$